# Make iCloud photos upload from phone less aggressively?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

If I have wifi access, after taking a photo, by the time I go to edit or share it mere seconds or minutes later it's already been uploaded from my phone to the cloud. This then means the big delay grabbing the photo from the cloud.

Is there *any* way to try to make that better, other than turning off "optimize photo storage", which I can't do given my phone+library size.

(I'd also accept a `rdar:://` number if this is known issue)

Comment: This isn't a bug, Apple designed it to feel practically like magic; you can take a photo, walk over to your Mac, and it's already there. You can actually prevent the auto-upload by turning on low power mode, or doing some network wizardry on the WiFi/router if it supports, but that's just working around what is essentially a design feature that doesn't work for you. Just so I'm clear: your phone immediately uploads, then discards the local copy of the photo, forcing you to re-download it before you can edit or share it? And though it uploads fast, it doesn't also download fast?

Comment: Not seeing why you wouldn't just disable WiFi if you are in a photo session where you know you want to post process the items before uploading. Am I missing something why the above makes sense? (and how a fast upload causes big delay grabbing the photo)

Comment: Maybe my root bug is that I aways see a big delay grabbing photos after they've been uploaded -- on the order of five to fifteen seconds.

Comment: @Harv: Your clarification is right on the money.

Comment: Opened http://www.openradar.me/14819497

Comment: I experience exactly the same behaviour. By the time I go check the photo, there’s always a delay as if it’s redownloading it... not to mention that downloading older photos from iCloud is slow as hell.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Low Power Mode. Then automatic uploading won't happen.

Some people keep Low Power Mode turned on all the time. If you don't, you may turn it on before taking the photo and then turn it off after you've done processing it or uploading it to social media.